# Infinite series: Integral test( Proof )

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

The following is a thought on the proof of the integral test. I am looking forward to knowing if it provides a correct understanding.

[image]

For $n>N$ we can write, $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} f(k)$.

We can observe, $\sum_{k=N}^{b-1} f(k) \Delta x > \int_{N}^{b}f(x)dx$, where the L.H.S of the inequality is the upper Riemann sum, $b-1>N$ and $\Delta x$ is a constant.

1) $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} \int_{N} ^{b}f(x)dx$ diverges.

It is clear that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} f(k) \Delta x$ diverges. Since $\Delta x$ is a constant, we can write,  $ \Delta x \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} f(k)$. This tells us that the series diverges.

We can observe that the lower sum is less than the finite integral. The series corresponding to the lower sum is $\sum_{k=N+1}^{b} f(k)$. As $b\rightarrow \infty$, the series can be written as, $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} f(k) - f(N)$. This diverges because the infinite sum diverges.

2) $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} \int_{N}^{b}f(x) dx$ converges.

Here, the lower sum converges because it is less than the finite integral. We can say, $\Delta x\sum_{k=N+1}^{b} f(k)$ converges and so does the series.

The series corresponding to the upper sum is $\sum_{N}^{\infty} f(k)$. This can be written as $\sum_{N+1}^{\infty} f(k)+f(N)$. This converges because the series converges.

This ends the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple proof using $f(k+1)\leq f(x)\leq f(k)~\forall~x\in [k,k+1]$ (since $f$ is decreasing).

We have,

$$\int_N^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=N}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leq \sum_{k=N}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=N}^\infty f(k)\tag1$$

Again,

$$\int_N^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=N}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\geq \sum_{k=N}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}f(k+1)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty f(k)\tag2$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have,

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty f(k)\leq\int_N^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leq\sum_{k=N}^\infty f(k)$$

from which the claim follows trivially.

Comment: This is simple and precise. +1!

Comment: I can summarize, for a decreasing function, $\Delta x \sum min[f(n)] < \int_{N}^{b} f(x) dx < \Delta x \sum max[f(n)]$. Both either converge or diverge.